# Is the comparison of PasswordHash happens at the client level or db level?

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i need to clarify a few things about user authentication, because i want to know hows its done properly,

I was told that the authentication is a process that concerns about security. So the authentication process should be hidden from the client as possible and the client should receive only a flag value (1= password is correct and authenticated, -1= incorrect password) and/or user name of the authenticated user. So it should be a SQL operation that should occur in the back end. So the process in detail should be, client form sends user name and hashed /encrypted password to SQL, SQL authenticates and it sends 1/-1 with the user name to the client as the return value and the output.

But when i search online, on user authentications, that was not the case, all the threads i have seen on web, either the app is windows or web, developers do two operations:

1. In SQL server, the saltHash value of the password is searched by user name then return the saltHash value along with the PasswordHash to the client form / or to the business layer
2. In the client or in BLL, Use the entered password and the returned saltHash value to generate a PasswordHash and then compare this passwordHash with the returned passwordHash. if match password is correct if not password is incorrect.

Is this actually how developers write code to authenticate a user in a login event? If so basically the password comparison happens at the client side(either in the form or in the business layer) then wouldn't this be huge security risk by exposing the actual saltHash and passwordHash to the client?

if some one could write me some code to demonstrate SQL and C# the login / authentication process, would be a delight!

PS- when you reply please do not use LINQ, LINQ to SQL or entity framework. At the moment i dont know them. still learning them. Please reply from Ado .NET

thanks

Comment: You need to describe your scenario a bit better.  Is this a web server, a desktop client/server app, or a desktop client app communicating directly with an SQL server?  I'm not sure what is leading you to the conclusion that there's any benefit to running the hash algorithm within SQL.

Comment: At the moments i'm working on a windows forms application and the SQL server is in a LAN environment. i thought web apps and windows app could use a common authentication methodology, it would be convenient to have a common authentication engine for windows and web app, wouldnt it? i refer to an engine as a separate class

Comment: also i was thinking about windows app and later wants to add a web app, could use a common SQL script(s) for the authentication process along with common validation classes in the client or in the business layer

Comment: To add: It sounds like you may be hashing your salt. This provides no more security than the unhashed salt, and may give you a false sense of security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a much larger pros/cons discussion, and it is hard to state it general. Pros of client-side hashing:

- Since cryptographically secure hashes are computationally intensive, by pushing them to the client, the load from the server is decreased.
- The server never gets to see the actual passwords, and since users share passwords between sites, if your system was to ever become compromised, you can make a claim that the passwords were not leaked.

Pros of server-side hashing:

- The code for computing hashes does not to be written for multiple clients, that is for various mobile devices, such as Windows Phone, Android, and IOS as well as browser. Sometimes, specialized code needs to be written for browsers too when there are compatibility differences.
- The hashes can be more "secure", e.g. you can have random salts for every user, which makes it computationally expensive for someone to brute force attack the passwords should the database be compromised. This gives more time for you to inform users should a breach occur and for users to change the passwords.

Some other guidelines:

- Never store passwords, whether encrypted or plaintext, in the DB. You cannot guarantee that everyone who has access to the DB will not look at the passwords, hacked, or make a mistake and compromise them.
- Such traffic must always go over TLS or SSL, which will guard against many attacks (such as eavesdropping, MITM, replay, etc.)
- Always use cryptographic functions (such as SHA2 for hashes, PBKDF2 for deriving salts, etc.) for all cryptographic operations.

The following are some guidelines on how to approach password hashing both for client vs server scenarios.

*If hashing is on the server:*

- When the user first registers:

  - Generate a random salt
  - Hash the password using this salt
  - Store both the salt and the password hash in the DB
- When the user comes to login

  - Read the salt from the DB
  - Compute the password hash
  - Compare with that in the DB

*If hashing is on the client:*

- When the user first registers:

  - Generate a salt based on some user attribute, such as user name, on the client
  - Hash the password using the salt on the client
  - Send the password hash to the server, and store the DB
- When the user comes to login

  - Generate the salt based on the same user attribute (i.e you can always use user name for example)
  - Hash the password using the salt on the client
  - Send the password hash to the server, compare with the one in DB

Comment: thanks for the detailed description : ) but i have a question in the bullet point "When user comes to login" you have mentioned "Compute the password Hash", What do u mean by this?, The sers table has a column called PasswordHash along with PasswordSalt. When the user login, both user name and password (hashed) is sent to database right? could you give me a sample code on this?

Comment: @AndrewMC I updated my answer for clarity. Sorry, I do not have any sample code and unfortunately, I have not used Sers. My response is agnostic of any platform or protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The method may be the same between a client/server application and a web app, but a windows app directly accessing a SQL database is a different matter. You probably do want to avoid disclosing the hashed password, but the salt doesn't need to be private. You could get the salt for the user and hash client side, then compare server-side.

I don't know if SQL has actual password hashing algorithms (mcrypt, PBKDF2, etc.) or is limited to purely cryptographic algorithms like the SHA family, but a benefit of hashing outside the server is that you can choose your hash algorithm.  You can also build some logic around it.  For example, you can store which hash algorithm is in use for an individual user, and then if it's broken in the future you can update them to a more secure algorithm the next time they log in.

You also have to realize that, whatever you do, there's little actual security beyond your SQL authentication. It's fairly trivial to modify the program to ignore what the SQL server responds with and proceed as if the login was successful. If you want actual security, you'll need an application server sitting between the client and the database. It's also trivial to decomplie the program, see what it does and use that information directly or in another program, bypasing authentication entirely.

Regarding reuse, it would be a better approach to seperate the authentication into a separate module and reuse that module in both applications.  ASP.NET has some [robust authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) built in, so I would look to that, either to use or as an example.  `Crypto.HashPassword()` already uses the currently-accepted best practice as long as you provide it with a relatively long (say 8+ character) random salt for each user.

Comment: To compare hashes in teh client is easy but not secure. But the the comparison needs to occur in the SQL server, then i should send the user entered password to login form in secured way. Hashing is the option. I was told use a Random Salt.using RNGCryptoServiceProvider then use the salt to hash the password and save the salt in the database.

Comment: but if i do this at user login, the saltHash will be different to what is stored in the database when the user registered him self. Therefore even the user enters correct credentials it will NOT authenticate. So i cannot use Random SaltHash technique i mentioned in the sample code above. So what is the secured way to send the password to the SQL server?

Comment: You retrieve the users salt from the database, hash the password with the salt, then send this to the database.  It's all a bit of a hack, however, as you really want a third system to handle authentication and enforce permissions.

Answer (score 0):

i would use the following method to get a random salt, but i cannot use this in the login user event, because even the user enters correct credntials, it will return failed authentication. this is because the entered password in the login form will be hashed with the random salt, this salt is different to whats in the database for this user

```
    private static byte[] GetSalt()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] b = new byte[32];
        rng.GetBytes(b);
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the users table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[LoginName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[UserName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
[EmailAddress] [varchar](256) NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[UserPasswordHash] [varbinary](64) NULL,
[UserPasswordSalt] [varbinary](32) NULL
)
GO
```